# Why is this q/kdb+ join more efficient? replacing a 2-column left-join with each-xgroup-1-column left joins

Tags: left-join, query-optimization, kdb

I was playing around with left-joining two in-memory tables. Both tables include columns `` `date`sym `` with a couple of millions of rows each and are sorted by date/sym with  `` `s#date `` set.

I was doing initially a naive left-join using:

`t: t1 lj 2!t2;`

and it was taking ~15s, then I played around and wrote it like:

`` t: ungroup {flip flip[x] lj 1!flip y}'[`date xgroup t1;`date xgroup t2]; ``

and this dropped runtime to 0.5s while yielding the same result (at least on my tables).

I don't understand why this would be more efficient. Would this be expected? Or am I doing something wrong that's preventing `lj` from automatically doing something more efficiently than it currently is?

Comment: Are you able to share representative data? Or failing that an idea of relative size of t1 Vs t2? I have a feeling it's to do with relative amount of iteration on t2 but that's just a hunch. Also worth noting at this point that flips on tables Vs dict amounts to a bit of pointer magic so is free for our purposes.

Comment: @user20349 I think it was roughly 300 distinct dates and 10000 distinct symbols. I also timed ```t1[`date`sym] inter t2[`date`sym]```, and that operation took as long as the entire join, so I'd guess it's spending all of its time in trying to match the keys; but I don't understand why it's not doing it one date at a time automatically as I wrote it out in my fast version.